# How to use PartialFunction.applyOrElse

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I have a `PartialFuncton[Throwable,Future[Result]]` called *errorMap* to transform an throwable to a result or failed future. I can do it via `lift` and `getOrElse` like this:

```
val x: Future[Result] = errorMap.lift(e).getOrElse(Future.failed(e))
```

I figure the same should be achievable with `applyOrElse`, but I can't seem to figure out how to call it to achieve this end. Am I misunderstanding what `applyOrElse` is for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `applyOrElse` takes a function-- in your case a `(Throwable) => Future[Result]`

Pass it a function like this:

`errorMap.applyOrElse(e, _ => Future.failed(e))`

or simply

`errorMap.applyOrElse(e, Future.failed)`

Comment: I must have been fatfingering my attempts. I swear i tried several variations of using Future.failed as the second argument. Thanks!